# When deploying spring app to azure in VS code, what's the endpoint to access the app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, visual-studio-code

I'm new to this and I followed the instructions here [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-apps#:~:text=Java%20on%20Azure%20Spring%20Apps%201%20Scenario%20We,...%206%20Deploy%20to%20Azure%20Spring%20Apps%20](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-apps#:%7E:text=Java%20on%20Azure%20Spring%20Apps%201%20Scenario%20We,...%206%20Deploy%20to%20Azure%20Spring%20Apps%20) to deploy the "hello world" app to azure. However, it's not clear to me how to access the deployed spring app? When I stream logs, I can see "Tomcat initialized with port(s): 1025 (http)".

I tried following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/quickstart?WT.mc_id=Portal-AppPlatformExtension&tabs=Azure-CLI

and used

```
 https://<service instance name>-<app-name>.azuremicroservices.io/
```

and it didn't work.

How do I find out how to access this deployed app on Azure? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because when the referenced tutorial is followed, there is no issue.  The OP realized after posting the question that a step of the tutorial had not been performed.  Once that step was performed, things worked out just as the tutorial suggested....hence this question adds no value to what is fundamentally an off-site resource.

Comment: Yes. I agree. How do I close this? Delete?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After deploying in VSCode following the steps, you need to also make select the app deployed in azure explorer and "assign public endpoint". Then following this link and it's accessible

```
https://<service instance name>-<app-name>.azuremicroservices.io/.
```